# Comparison of Lp norm of matrix and its entry wise norm.

Tags: matrices, norms, operator-norms

I need to know the relation between operator norm of a matrix i.e. $ \Vert A\Vert_p$ for case of p=1 and 2 and its entry wise Frobenius norm $ \Vert A\Vert_F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is $n\times n$, then
$$\frac1{\sqrt n}\|A\|_F\le\|A\|_1\le\sqrt n\,\|A\|_F,\qquad \|A\|_2\le\|A\|_F\le\sqrt n\,\|A\|_2.$$
More generally, if $A$ is $n\times m$, then
$$\frac1{\sqrt m}\|A\|_F\le\|A\|_1\le\sqrt n\,\|A\|_F,\qquad \|A\|_2\le\|A\|_F\le\min(\sqrt n\,,\sqrt m)\,\|A\|_2.$$
To see that these inequalities are sharp, take respectively the matrices
$$1_n\otimes \vec e^1,\quad \vec e^1\otimes 1_m,\qquad 1_n\otimes 1_m$$
for the first three inequalities. For the last one, complete the identity matrix by zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If i say $ A$ is of size $n\times m   (m>>n)$, so what will be the factor in the above equation $\sqrt{n}$ or $\sqrt{m}$.